# Want to plot graph side by side

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I wan to two plots side by side instead of this vertically, right now it's showing one by one
[image: ![Image from]

```
def scatter_plot(surrogate, building, actual, pred,index):

#calculating max and min x axis range
min_range=pred.min()-10
max_range=pred.max()+10
min_domain=actual.min()-10
max_domain=actual.max()+10

#scaling and creating scatter plot
plt.axes([0, 0, 2, 2])
plt.scatter(x=actual,y=pred, marker="o") #(y = predicted)
#plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Actual Values', fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel('Predicted Values', fontsize = 20)
plt.title(f'{building.idf}_{building.epw}_{variable} Scatter Plot of NN vs E+', fontsize= 25)

#adding regression line
plt.plot([min_domain, max_domain], [min_range, max_range], color='g', linestyle='-', linewidth=1,label='regression')
#adding line passing minimum and maximum actual points
plt.plot([min_domain, max_domain],[min_domain, max_domain],color='r',linestyle='-',linewidth=1,label='actual point line')

#adding legend
plt.legend(loc='lower right')


#calculating error metrics
location = building.metadata['building_attributes']['Location']
building_type = building.idf
df = csv.loc[(csv['id'] == surrogate.surrogate_id) & 
             (csv['Location'] == location) & (csv['Building Type'] == building_type)]
rmse = df[f'{variable} RMSE'].values[0]
r2 = df[f'{variable} R2'].values[0]

#Adding Error metric annotations
textstr = '\n'.join((r'Total Error Metrics', r'$RMSE=%.2f$' % (rmse, ),r'$R2=%.2f$' % (r2, )))
props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='ivory', alpha=0.5)
plt.text(max_range, max_domain, textstr, fontsize=20, verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)

#calculating x and y range
axes = plt.gca()
y_min, y_max = axes.get_ylim()
x_min, x_max = axes.get_xlim()

#Coordinates of interested area
percentile = 10
nth_percentile = np.percentile(actual,percentile)
bottom, left, width, height = 0, 0, nth_percentile,nth_percentile 

try:     
    x_hist = x_min +(x_max - x_min)/9 #may have to change value 9
    #calculating lines for selected area
    x1, y1 = [left, x_hist], [bottom+height, (y_max + y_min)/2]
    x2, y2 = [left + width, x_hist], [bottom + height, (y_max + y_min)/2]
    L_act = []
    L_pred = []
    for x, y in zip(actual, pred):
        if left <= x <= width+left:
            if bottom<= y <= height + bottom:
                L_act.append(x)
                L_pred.append(y)
    
    #adding rectangle for selected area
    rect=mpatches.Rectangle((left, bottom),width, height, fill = False, color = "black",linewidth = 2)
    plt.gca().add_patch(rect)
    
    #calculating error metrics for selected area
    rmse = RMSE(L_act, L_pred)
    r2 = R2(L_act, L_pred)
    
    #adding lines to indicated the selected area
    plt.plot(x1, y1, x2, y2, color = 'black', linewidth = 2)

    #adding histogram
    plt.axes([0.2, 1, .6, .6], facecolor='w')
    plt.hist(L_act, 30)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])

    textstr = '\n'.join((r'Selected Section Error Metrics', r'$RMSE=%.2f$' % (rmse, ),r'$R2=%.2f$' % (r2, )))
    props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='ivory', alpha=0.8)
    
    #adding error metrics annotations for selected area
    axes = plt.gca()
    y_min, y_max = axes.get_ylim()
    x_min, x_max = axes.get_xlim()
    plt.text(x_min + x_min/10, y_max - y_max/30, textstr, fontsize=10, verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)
    
except ValueError:
    print("Selected section doesn't contain any data points")
    
    
plt.show()
```

I tried using a subplot but that didn't work

```
def s_plot(surrogate,building):
figure, axis = plt.subplots(1, 2)
actual, pred = np.array(surrogate.test_samples[variable].values[:]), np.array(surrogate.training_samples[variable].values[:])
  actual_train, pred_train = np.array(surrogate.train_actual[variable].values[:]), np.array(surrogate.train_pred[variable].values[:])

data =[[actual,pred],[actual_train, pred_train]
for ax,i in zip(axes.flatten(),data):
    scatter_plot(surrogate,building,i[0],i[1],ax)
```

Here I am using axes instead of plt but there are so many parameters that axes doesn't have such as gca, scaling using axes, etc. and I am not able to plot histogram by subplot use
Is there any way to plot this side by side

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example of using histogram with subplots:

```
def func(ax):
    # example data
    mu = 100  # mean of distribution
    sigma = 15  # standard deviation of distribution
    x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(437)

    num_bins = 50
    # the histogram of the data
    n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x, num_bins, density=True)

    # add a 'best fit' line
    y = ((1 / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * sigma)) *
         np.exp(-0.5 * (1 / sigma * (bins - mu))**2))
    ax.plot(bins, y, '--')
    ax.set_xlabel('Smarts')
    ax.set_ylabel('Probability density')
    ax.set_title(r'Histogram of IQ: $\mu=100$, $\sigma=15$')

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
func(ax1)
func(ax2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you
If I want to take some from graph and plot scatter in that graph (for example you can see  picture attached in question, scatter plot and took some point and made histogram) and what to use to scale graph like plt.axes[(0,0,2,2)] here and what is alternative of plt.gca in subplotting?

Comment: generate an axis for the inset graph, like: axins = ax1.inset_axes([0.75, 0.75, 0.1, 0.1]). Then plot against this axis.

Comment: Got it thanks, another ques leading to that
def s_plot(variable):
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    func(ax1)
    func(ax2)
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.show()

variable=[1,2,3,4]
for i in variable:
    s_plot(i)
    print(i)

In output I want to print all 'i' first and then show plots, instead, I want to plot the value corresponding to i then plot then i, and so on, 

Ouput--
1
2
3
4
plot1
plot2
plot3
plot4

I want 
plot1
1
plot2
2
plot3
3
plot4
4

What can I try to obtain this?

Comment: sorry @siddharth, find it hard to follow comment above, maybe raise a new question with that specific question.